# Why .NET Core's model validator shows me names of my model properties instead of JSON fields names on validation messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
     [JsonProperty("screen_width")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required width")]
     public string ScreenWidth { get; set; }  
}
```

And validation in my controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    [Route("/api/v1.0/test")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] MyModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected JSON body is:

```
{
    "screen_width": "1900"
}
```

But I will pass for example:

```
{
    "hello": "azazazazazaa!"   
}
```

So, what I will see as the response? 
The following:

[image]

But it's strange behavior! My clients don't know about `ScreenWidth`. It's property of my class. Why clients must know about it? They know only about `screen_width`.

So, my question is: how to change this behavior to get this validation message:

```
{
  "screen_width": [
    "Required width"
  ]
}
```

P.S I use .NET Core 3.1 and I use `using Newtonsoft.Json;` for `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came about the following interesting article [here](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/november/using-displayname-attribute-for-model-validation-output-in-aspnet-mvc-core/)

Try with the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
     [JsonProperty("screen_width")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required width")]
     [DisplayName("screen_width")]
     public string ScreenWidth { get; set; }  
}
```

But this on it's own will not work. You need to disable the internal model state filter.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
    {  
        ...  
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>  
            {  
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;  
            });  
        ...  
    }
```

And then, create another filter

```
public class DisplayNameValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute  
{  
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)  
    {  
        if (context.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)  
        {  
            var modelType = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters  
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.BindingInfo.BindingSource.Id.Equals("Body", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))?.ParameterType; //Get model type  

            var expandoObj = new ExpandoObject();  
            var expandoObjCollection = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>)expandoObj; //Cannot convert IEnumrable to ExpandoObject  

            var dictionary = context.ModelState.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)  
                .Where(v => v.Value.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)  
                .ToDictionary(  
                k =>  
                {  
                    if (modelType != null)  
                    {  
                        var property = modelType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(k.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));  
                        if (property != null)  
                        {  
                            //Try to get the attribute  
                            var displayName = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()?.DisplayName;  
                            return displayName ?? property.Name;  
                        }  
                    }  
                    return k.Key; //Nothing found, return original vaidation key  
                },  
                v => v.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList() as Object); //Box String collection  
            foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)  
            {  
                expandoObjCollection.Add(keyValuePair);  
            }  
            dynamic eoDynamic = expandoObj;  
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(eoDynamic);  
        }  
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);  
    }  
}
```

Now just use the following:

```
public class MyController
{
    [Route("/api/v1.0/test")]
    [DisplayNameValidationFilter]  
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromBody] MyModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already have tried it. Sorry, I did not say about it. It does not work.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I figured it out it did not work and some quick research lead me to custom validation filters with `Expando objects`.

Comment: Now your solution works for me! Thank you. I can't believe that Microsoft don't have standard solution for these cases. It's obviously, am I right?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak: It's not obvious, when you know how it works. Validation error messages, weren't sent back to the user (prior to the "Problem Details" Api in ASP.NET Core 2.1 or 2.2). valdiation messages are built within the [ModelStateDictionary](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src/ModelBinding/ModelStateDictionary.cs).This one is generated during model binding and has no knowledge which serializer (json.net or System.Text.Json, xml, protobuf, key/value form-data) is used and knows even less, what's returned (request can accept json but return xml)

Comment: And as such, the properties of your **model** are used, and C# properties by name convention are PascalCase. When its serilized back into json, the property name is not a property name anymore but a `value` of the `ModelStateDictionary`/`ModelStateEntry` class. If you need it for your application, you need to transform it yourself. Or easier: Do case insensitive comparision in your web application